# populate data from the current form to the other register form

Tags: zend-framework

i have an user form which he has to fill before moving on to registration page ->

what i want to check is if the user is above a certain age and has selected India has his country then only he can register and proceed to registration form

i am done with calculating age of user and validating it.

i need to check if India has been selected in if condition

of the controller in z end-framework

and i need to populate the data  in the other form with user registration with their date and country in a date-picker and a drop down respectively how can i do it ?

is it correct to check like

if($post['country'] == 'India') can anyone guide me on how to move this data to another form and populate it with this info ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the field names from the previous form are the same as the new form, you can just use the `$form->populate` like this:

```
$form->populate($_POST);
```

For more information regarding, have a look  [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html)

Comment: thanks i am having an problem fetching the value of the country can u tell me how can i use it compare it in a if condition ur method is getting me a fatal error Call to a member function getValue() on a non-object .

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you using same field names on both forms?

Comment: actually am working with datepicker can u help on that i have to fetch the dob date from datepicker to the signup form how could i do that i am using two forms one is check point which gets the dobs from datepicker and i need to send it to the signup page where it should be poplated and show his dob in datpicker without using zend_form how can it be done in a simple way .

Comment: actually i used new zend_namespace for storing session variables thanks for ur help friends i will try this method too

Comment: @Niklas can u help me find a better way to do this in session my method is working but not satisfied .

Comment: @Justin ZEND beginner you will need to describe your problem more in detail and what exactly you are doing and what isn't working